# uploadprogress.so is installed, but does not appear in phpinfo

Tags: rhel6, php.ini, php, pecl

I'm on RHEL6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)), but I've upgraded PHP to version 5.4.16.  I've downloaded and installed the PECL [uploadprogress](http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress) library version 1.0.3.1 that is supposed to be compatible with my version of PHP:

```
sudo pecl install uploadprogress
```

Installation went without a glitch, and I've verified that:

```
/usr/lib64/php/modules/uploadprogress.so
```

exists and is compatible with my architecture.

I've added the following line to `php.ini`:

```
extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/uploadprogress.so
```

and I've restarted the *httpd* service.

However, when I look at the phpinfo page, uploadprogress does not appear aywhere.

Usually, when this happens, it is because the library is not compatible with the PHP version.  However, I do not believe that this is the case here.

Let me add that I've no problem installing other PHP extensions on this system.

Any ideas for what else to try to find out what is wrong?

Comment: How did you upgrade PHP? Also which `php.ini` did you edit?

Comment: Its been a while, but I believe I got PHP from Red Hat SCL (`yum install php54-php`).  I edited `/opt/rh/php54/root/etc/php.ini` - which is the php.ini-file listed in *phpinfo*.  I've verified that this is indeed read on startup by changing `memory_limit` and observing that it is changed when I restart *httpd*